# What is the default Swagger UI path in Springdoc?

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using the Springdoc and running a sample project but not able to see Swagger UI.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.32</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried the following URLs but Swagger UI is not opening:

```
localhost:8080/v3/apidocs
localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
localhost:8080/swagger-ui/
```

What is the correct Swagger UI path when using Springdoc?

Answer (score 2):

if you use SpringBoot v3 you should use springdoc v2, in this case add org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0 to your dependencies instead of springdoc-openapi-ui (the latest version is 1.7.x) - this works fine with SpringBoot v2, but still not works with v3

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties the default path should be

> /swagger-ui.html

Confirm if you have configured a custom context path, because if you did then you need to add the context path before, like

> /my-custom-path/swagger-ui.html